# Is SignalR suitable for my web application, or is there a better choice?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I am going to be building an auction website using ASP.NET MVC with an MS SQL Server database backend, and I've been looking at SignalR as part of it.  What I envision is using SignalR to provide real-time updates of auctions as bidding occurs or some other action happens on each auction.
Part of this is that I want to display multiple auctions on a page and have each auction updating in the client's web browser.  Is this something that SignalR would be the right technology for, or is there something else I should consider?

Comment: This question is considered off-topic here as this is not really a programming question. It is primarily opinion based. However, I think that almost every opinion would be the same...this is what you want to use.

Comment: Thanks for the info about topic appropriateness, and your reply.

Comment: This question is a bit broad.  The prima facie answer is "if it's the best fit for your specific software requirements."

Comment: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/supported-platforms

Comment: Perhaps you're right, but I was debating the wisdom of "rolling my own" AJAX or using something like SignalS, so I was looking for opinions, that's all. You're right that "it depends" is probably the closest answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, SignalR is what you are looking for. Create a group for each auction and broadcast to all users in that group

Comment: I'lol have to study on that, since part of this is to give users real-time updates on auctions they are bidding on specifically and to browse active auctions by category or some other criteria.